# Declaring an (unused) integer causing the whole program to malfunction?

Tags: c++, debugging, variables

I've reduced my code as much as I can in order to show this strange error that keeps coming up.

I have a program here that works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int * elements;
    // int size = 10;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        elements[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "Hi";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, as soon as I uncomment the one commented line, everything crashes. Nothing prints, and Windows comes up with an error saying that the program has stopped responding. Changing the variable name does not effect the program.

This is a strange error I haven't seen before. If anyone could offer some sort of help, it would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** I see now that I forgot to allocate memory for elements. However, I still don't understand how entering "int size = 10" somehow stopped the program from crashing.

Comment: "This is a strange error I haven't seen before" - no it's not! Beginners do it all the time...

Comment: Thank you for reducing the code to the smallest size that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unused integer has nothing to do with your problem.

You didn't allocate any memory for the `elements` pointer.  You try to access ten elements from this uninitialized pointer.  Your program has undefined behavior, and is wrong even if it appears to work.

> However, I still don't understand how entering "int size = 10" somehow
>   stopped the program from crashing.

Undefined behavior means anything can happen, and seemingly innocuous pieces of code may cause your program to have different behavior, even if those pieces of code have no apparent relation to the actual offending code.  That's why the behavior is called "undefined".

Answer (score 1):

The commented out `int` has nothing to do with your error.

You haven't allocated any memory for your `elements` pointer (array):

```
  int * elements;
```

That declares a pointer to `int`. But no space is allocated for the array of integers.

Accessing memory you don't own is *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to allocate memory to store the elements.  As a result, you access memory that isn't properly prepared and you get *undefined behaviour*, anything can happen.  You should consider using `vector`s instead, much easier and safer than pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>  //  You must include this to get vectors
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<int> elements(10); // to create space for 10 ints
    // int size = 10;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        elements[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "Hi";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, it's safer to use `elements.at(i) = 10` instead of `elements[i] = 10`, because the `at` will automatically check the size of the vector and ensure it is big enough.  With `[i]`, no checking is performed.